# Technique Needed To Create Such Java2D Look n Feel

Tags: java

I saw the following nice looking tool tips, created using JavaScript JQuery Toolkit.

I was planning to implement a similar look in my Java standalone application.

I was wondering what is the techniques needed to create such effect?

http://sites.google.com/site/yanchengcheok/Home/Tooltip.PNG?attredirects=0

The things come out from my head are :

```
Transparency - java.awt.AlphaComposite
Gradient Background - java.awt.GradientPaint
Background Shadow - ???
White Line Around The Black Box - LineBorder ?
```

What is the keyword I shall look for, for the technology marked with ???

Thanks.

Or more preferable, some ready-made library, that can be displayed along JXLayer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Filthy Rich Clients](http://filthyrichclients.org/) is a good book for learning how to use Java to create graphical components/effect like the tooltip you want.